# Display a custom button linked to a random product in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce, product

I am using Wordpress and Woocommerce and I am trying to add a custom button linked to a random product, so that every time that someone clicks on the link it takes them to a different product single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** The following example will display a button linked to a random product:

```
// Get a random product id (array)
$random_product_array = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$random_product_id    = reset($random_product_array); // Get the random product ID

// Display a linked button to the random product
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($random_product_id) . '" class="button alt">' . __("Go to a random product") . '</a>';
```

You can even embed that in a shortcode function like:

```
add_shortcode( 'random_product_button', 'shortcode_random_product_button' );
function shortcode_random_product_button( $atts ) {
    // Get a random product id (array)
    $random_product_array = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $random_product_id    = reset($random_product_array); // Get the random product ID

    // Display a linked button to the random product
    return '<a href="' . get_permalink($random_product_id) . '" class="button alt">' . __("Go to a random product") . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:**

1) Inside a Page or post content text Editor *(or a text widget)*:

```
[random_product_button]
```

2) On a php template or code:

```
echo do_shortcode("[random_product_button]");
```